# Rename list element based on file names - R

Tags: r

I wish to read multiply file contents (file names are stored in lfFolder) to a list (myList) using the script below. How can I rename the list element name based on the first 5 letters of the read filename?

Script:

```
folderLocation<-"E:/"
lfFolder <- list.files(folderLocation, pattern = "\\.txt$",full.names=TRUE)

myList <- lapply(lfFolder, function(readFName) { read.table(readFName, header=T, sep=",")$xGIS})
```

Comment: Maybe `myList <- setNames(myList, substr(list.files(folderLocation, pettern="\\.txt"), 1, 5))`?

Comment: changed pettern to pattern and it works